# My share extension does not show up among the dropbox extensions

Tags: ios, dropbox, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

I have the following in my extension's plist

```
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
                    <dict>
                            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileURLWithMaxCount</key>
                            <integer>1</integer>
                            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                            <integer>1</integer>
                    </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
            <string>MainInterface</string>
            <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
```

So my extension shows up in Photos and Snapchat, but not Dropbox.
What should I tweak to get listed in dropbox share choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
And the documentation for the missing key is/was here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW11